# Edit receber caption de varios labels

Tags: delphi

Gostaria que um `TEdit` recebesse o valor de um `TLabel` e ao clicar em outra `TLabel` a propriedade *caption* concatenaria o que foi recebido antes.

Ex :

```
edit.text := valorlabel1 valorlabel2 valorlabel3 .....
```

Tentei usar uma *variável global*, mas uma hora ficará inviável.

```
var variavel_global1 : string;
```

Ao clicar na label:

```
procedure TForm3.edt_variavel1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
edit1.Text := edt_variavel1.caption + ' ';
variavel_global1 := edit1.Text;
end;
```

Existe alguma outra forma disso ser feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira mais simples seria, no evento onclick do label:

Edi1.Text := Edit1.Text + TLabel(Sender).caption+ ' ';

Comment: Bacana cara, era o que eu precisava...
Começou bem no site, bem vindo